# Browser is not redirecting but url is changing

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, redirect, browser

I want to redirect my page by clicking on entire row.

For that my HTML table row is below which is created by javascript.

```
id = 1;
<tr onclick="document.location.href='http://localhost/emailc/emailCampaignEdit/"+id+"'">
    <td><b>abc</b></td>
</tr>
```

before clicking on above code my browser's url is `http://localhost/emailc`

After click on code I want to redirect my page on this url `http://localhost/emailc/emailCampaignEdit/1`

Browsers url is changes perfectly on clicking. but browser is not redirecting to that url. If I refresh browser on that url then it works as I want.

I have tried this also for testing the syntax:

```
<tr onclick="document.location.href='http://www.google.com'">
    <td><b>abc</b></td>
</tr>
```

It works perfectly, browser is completely redirecting to google page and I have also tested other redirecting codes likes `window.location.href` or `window.location.assign` or `window.location` everything has same problem.

Comment: How are you assigning value to `ID` variable?

Comment: are you using any kind of virtual servers , like xamp ?

Comment: ID is dynamic but for reducing the complexity and for convenience, i have write id = 1;

Comment: @ProllyGeek no, i am using Ubuntu as operating system, which separately contains Apache, PHP and all...

Comment: In Which browser you are testing this? As your code works perfectly on IE-11 and Chrome, i have just tested!

Comment: i am using chrome and firefox for testing

Comment: Check live fiddle, it wroks.. http://jsfiddle.net/anilk/8Qr5j/

Comment: try using window.open()

Answer (score 1):

```
<tr onclick="openWin('1')">
    <td><b>abc</b></td>
</tr>
<script>
function openWin(id)
{
window.open("http://localhost/emailc/emailCampaignEdit/"+id)
}
</script>
```

can you try this out ?

Edit :

you may use this function :

```
location.reload(false);
```

which will reload page from server , instead reloading page from cache , right after the url changes

so you should use :

```
function openWin(id)
    {
    window.open("http://localhost/emailc/emailCampaignEdit/"+id,"_self");
    location.reload(false);
    }
```

Comment: it opens a new tab , but not in same tab, when i use "_self" as second parameter then it stucks with the same problem as i mention in question

Comment: does it work properely when you open it in a new tab ?

Comment: i dont know what exactly the problem is , maybe a security issue , but what i can suggest is triggering a refresh programatically , is this suitable for you ?

Comment: @vishal i know it is not the correct way , but you can call it work around till we find the real issue , i edited my answer , so please tell me if it works.

Comment: then you may want to show full code related to this page , is it generated dynamically , or does it exist already on server ?

Comment: maybe you want to turn caching off if you are using google chrome.

Comment: the link is in table row which is generated dynamically by javascript. but <table> tag exist in server, the page is quite big, which make my question complex. please tell me why it works on simple page urls like "www.google.com" but not mine.

Comment: why should i turn caching off ?

Comment: because requests to localhost are different i think , but i think the issue is something with browser , have you tried using any other browser ? you did tell me what browser are you using ?

Comment: are there any calls on the new loading page ?

Comment: this gonna be hard to solve without reading the source code , we gonna waste much time here trying to figuring out the problem , so im sorry , unless you cant provide the source code , we will waste , you may consider offering a bounty to lure more experienced people , maybe they can help you more than i can .

Comment: omit your private stuff , upload the portions where you suspect the error to be at.

Answer (score 0):

```
var id = 1;
document.write('<table>'+
'<tr onclick="document.location.href=\'http://localhost/emailc/emailCampaignEdit'+id+'\'">'+
'<td><b>abc</b></td>'+
'</tr></table>');
```

Please try above code

Comment: my rows is created using javascript's insertrow(), document.write() doesn't help me in my application or for further processing

Comment: No dear, document write is just a example. As i tried your code there is '(quotes) issue in the URL.

Comment: can you tell me where?

Comment: in url, you can not use multiple quotes inside string.  If you want use there is right way by using \' instead of '

Comment: i did this but it doesn't create any difference.

Answer (score 0):

this should work, it works for me

```
var td = document.getElementsByTagName('td'), id = 1;

td[0].addEventListener('click', function(){location.assign('yourURL.php?id=' + id);}, false);
```

Note that document.location.href returns the URL of the page and does not redirect. Refer to http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_loc_href.asp for more information.

Comment: but why document.location.href is working on another pages like www.google.com

Comment: i get you now, what you're doing is assigning the href attribute so it changes the url to that and the browser opens the attribute that has been set but if you want to redirect then it is best to use location.assign especially when using events.

Comment: i have already write this in my question, i have tried window.location.assign. which also having a same problem.